# Service not found in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I'm getting an error where the service `AuthFilter` isn't found in angularjs. Sample jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/F5dhg/. I can't figure out why the service isn't found by the injector, because it is clarely present. Also, if I include `$injector` into the `config` block (instead of `AuthFilter`), and do `$injector.get('AuthFilter')` I get the same error, but if I do `$injector.has('AuthFilter')` I get `true`, and if I then again do `$injector.get('AuthFilter')` I get a cyclic dependency error. I'm fairly new to angularjs, and would appreciate any help I can get in solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module :

> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations
>   and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected
>   into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>   of services before they have been fully configured.

Can you not use a run block?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. But how are you then able to get stuff like `$routeProvider` during config? And can't I just change my service to work like that?

Comment: Err the text explains your question.  `$routeProvider` is a provider. And it's therefore available during config.  Custom services on the other hand.  As far as your second question goes - there's nothing wrong with your *service* - it's your *config* block that's the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out what the problem was, I just haven't figured out how to do what I want....

Anyways, I'm marking this as the answer, cause it showed me why it didn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is an example where I changed your service into a provider. Might help you. http://jsfiddle.net/ybeVz/1/

Answer (score -3):

try camel case notation and see what happens, authFilter instead of Auth...

Comment: kangoroo: Did you even try that in the fiddle?

Comment: no offense, but i am not here to try thing for people, just trying to help

Comment: I just figured something that was pure (incorrect) speculation that would have taken less than 30 seconds to try out yourself deserved to be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: ok, next time I ask you if it's ok to comment or to post an answer, then execute my decision.